# Коли треба вживати «по» в українській мові?

Tags: вживання-слів, прийменники

У [праці](https://maidan.org.ua//files/karavan/P1.HTM) «Пошук українського слова» Святослав Караванський пише, що «по» вживають в ось таких виразах:

- відпочивати по черзі
- відправляти панахиду по жертвах
- пізнавати по очах
- помагати по змозі
- читати по складах
- пізнавати по голосу

[OnlineCorrector](https://onlinecorrector.com.ua/uk/%D0%BF%D0%BE/) в таких:

- ударити по голові
- іти по воду
- їздити по містах
- відпочити по обіді
- читати по складах
- поратися по господарству
- по всьому (що по всьому?)

А [урок з МогоКласу](https://www.miyklas.com.ua/p/ukrainska-mova/11-klas/sintaksichna-norma-380223/slovospoluchennia-z-priimennikom-po-380391/re-93fd2b5b-a0c8-4e7d-9f56-09543f774e4e) і таких:

- отримувати по подарунку
- згадати по смерті
- брат по перу
- розпорядження по казармі
- карбувальник по сріблу

Чи міг би хтось скласти закономірність вживання «по»?

Comment: Є ще [стаття в СУМ-20](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=79312&page=2458) (якщо викинути звідти пункти, відмічені як розмовні, то вийде ще один варіант бачення того, коли _по_ доречне).